# Javascript array value undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am currently working on a REST API / website project, where my REST API has to return an array of objects from the server, via a response and using GSON to make a Json array out of the data. However, when trying to get values from the javascript array for the website, I keep getting undefined. This is the array:

```
var userArr =[
  {
    "0x1": {
      "firstName": "Test1",
      "lastName": "Test1",
      "hobbies": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Fodbold",
          "people": [
            "0x1"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "id": 1,
      "address": {
        "id": 1,
        "street": "Street1",
        "cityInfo": {
          "id": 1,
          "zipCode": "0555",
          "city": "Scanning"
        },
        "infoList": [
          "0x1",
          "0x2"
        ]
      },
      "phones": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "number": "123124",
          "info": "0x1"
        }
      ]
    }
];
```

When I try to call userArr[0].firstName, I get an error saying that it's undefined, even though the data is there. This is from a get call, which I am doing in my javascript from my REST API, which sends back this specific array. I have tried looping through the array, with multiple objects inside, however I am unable to retrieve any info at all.

Comment: You should do `userArr[0]["0x1"].firstName`, you have two nested objects

Comment: Admiral Ackbar: *its a typo!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `userArr` is an array of objects which do not have `firstName` property. They have only one property named `0x1` for some reason. And this `0x1` property has `firstName` property.

You can access `firstName` of `0x1` property using this notation:

```
userArr[0]["0x1"].firstName
```

Here is the working demo:

```js
var userArr = [{
  "0x1": {
    "firstName": "Test1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "hobbies": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Fodbold",
      "people": [
        "0x1"
      ]
    }],
    "id": 1,
    "address": {
      "id": 1,
      "street": "Street1",
      "cityInfo": {
        "id": 1,
        "zipCode": "0555",
        "city": "Scanning"
      },
      "infoList": [
        "0x1",
        "0x2"
      ]
    },
    "phones": [{
      "id": 1,
      "number": "123124",
      "info": "0x1"
    }]
  }
}];

console.log(userArr[0]["0x1"].firstName);
```

By the way, there is a missing closing } bracket in the end of the array in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you write this code this way it is easy to understand and find the problem

```
var userArr =[
  {
    "0x1": {
      "firstName": "Test1",
      "lastName": "Test1",
      "hobbies": [{"id": 1,"name": "Fodbold","people": ["0x1"]}],
      "id": 1,
      "address": {"id": 1,"street": "Street1","cityInfo": {"id": 1,"zipCode": "0555","city": "Scanning"},
      "infoList": ["0x1","0x2"]},
      "phones": [{"id": 1,"number": "123124","info": "0x1"}]
    }
  }
];
```

You also missing the last second bracket.
Then you could use this `console.log(userArr[0]["0x1"].firstName);`

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
userArr[0]["0x1"].firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase value `"0x1"` is dynamic, you can access it by using `Object.keys(userArr[0])[0]` to get the first key of the object.

Here is solution:

```js
var userArr = [{
  "0x1": {
    "firstName": "Test1",
    "lastName": "Test1",
    "hobbies": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Fodbold",
      "people": [
        "0x1"
      ]
    }],
    "id": 1,
    "address": {
      "id": 1,
      "street": "Street1",
      "cityInfo": {
        "id": 1,
        "zipCode": "0555",
        "city": "Scanning"
      },
      "infoList": [
        "0x1",
        "0x2"
      ]
    },
    "phones": [{
      "id": 1,
      "number": "123124",
      "info": "0x1"
    }]
  }
}];

console.log(userArr[0][Object.keys(userArr[0])[0]].firstName);
```